# How to preserve google account when using goole_sing_in on IOS

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin, google-oauth

Here is code that I have

```
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
        await googleUser.authentication;
    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );
```

I saw other apps are able to have memory about the account that I login or logout, but my app are not able to do it, every time I logout I'll have to retype the password.
This only happen on iOS, Android is fine.

this is what I got
[image]

but this is what I want 
[image]